# DSSesssion in delphi Xe5

Tags: web-services, delphi, rest

How to use DSSession to implements DataSnap authenticated sessions(HTTP/HTTPs)?????

My problems are:
  I try to login into Login.html, then login complete Server Redirect into home.html
    But in page Home.html not identified yet, So cant use Function.ServerMethod();

I wana to SetCredential(user:pass) in Home page used DSSession or anythings same.
  In Home page , if not login, Redirect into Login again.

Comment: Please show some code that reproduces the behaviour. It is harder to tell what happens if you only describe it.

Answer (score 0):

Before in Login.html confirm user and pass :
    procedure TWebModule1.DSAuthenticationManager1UserAuthenticate(
      Sender: TObject; const Protocol, Context, User, Password: string;
      var valid: Boolean; UserRoles: TStrings);

```
var
  session: TDSSession;
begin
  //valid := True;

FormMain.Debug(['Before IsLogin : ',IsLogin],'?');
if not IsLogin then
IsLogin := (User = Password) and (user <> '');
valid := IsLogin;

FormMain.Debug(['IsLogin : ',IsLogin],'?');
FormMain.Debug(['UserAuthenticate :',User,Password],'?');

if valid = true then
  FormMain.Debug(['UserAuthenticate : valid = true'],'?')
else
  FormMain.Debug(['UserAuthenticate : valid = false'],'?');

if valid then
  begin
    Session := TDSSessionManager.GetThreadSession;

    Session.PutData ('username', user);
    UserRoles.Add ('standard');
    if User = 'admin' then
      UserRoles.Add ('admin');
  end;
end;
```

Then redirect into Home.html. But in this page cant use Serverfunction(). ( errror 404, not Unauthorize)